# What is a knight?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, fighter, archetype

I have been reading several archetypes and I ran across an archetype called [Weapon Bearer Squire](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/weapon-bearer-squire) whose ability description reads as follows:

> At 1st level, once per round, a knight can retrieve an item carried by his weapon bearer squire as a move action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity. In addition, a weapon bearer squire can pick up items dropped by her knight as an immediate action without provoking attacks of opportunity.

However, I am not sure which class the ability refers to as the knight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This archetype requires a lot of context. In *Knights of the Inner Sea*, the Weapon Bearer Squire archetype and other 'Squire' archetypes are presented as ways to customize the NPC you gain via the [Squire feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/squire/).

The book text prefacing the Squire feat talks about a number of different Knightly Orders in the Golarion setting for Pathfinder (there are seven defined political orders plus some religious orders). It also has this important bit of clarification:

> A character may gain the aid of a squire by becoming a member of a knightly order and taking the Squire feat. The squire must be a member of the same order as the knight.

**Therefore, in the Golarion setting, the 'Knight' being referred to by this archetype is the Player Character that takes the Squire feat and is a member of a knightly order.**